# Iterative selection by attribute and then location using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, select-by-location, iterator

I am trying to divide and record a road dataset using a GRID I just created. Is there a way to perform that using only the ModelBuilder or do I have to use Python (never tried before..)?

Here is below what I tried so far but it's not (yet?) working

[image]

**For** goes from 1 to 42 (the number of records in the GRID).
**Select Layer By Attribute** appears to work well using GRID_ID that goes also from 1 to 42. However I just reached an impasse, I don't know if the **Select by location** works or how to iteratively record the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, the first part of the model was correct it was just missing the following tools to record the iterative selections:

**Make Feature Layer** and **Copy Features** in this order